# Batching Elements in Google Cloud Dataflow Pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'm looking into grouping elements during the flow into batch groups that are grouped based on a batch size.

In Pseudo code:

```
PCollection[String].apply(Grouped.size(10))
```

Basically converting a PCollection[String] into PCollection[List[String]] where each list now contains 10 elements. As it is batch and in case it doesn't evenly divide the last batch would contain the left over elements.

I have two ugly ideas with windows and fake timestamps or a GroupBy using keys based on a random index to distribute evenly, but this seems like a to complex solution for the simple problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is similar to a variety of questions on how to batch elements. Take a look at these to get you started:

[Can datastore input in google dataflow pipeline be processed in a batch of N entries at a time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35065109/can-datastore-input-in-google-dataflow-pipeline-be-processed-in-a-batch-of-n-ent/35068341#35068341)

[Partition data coming from CSV so I can process larger patches rather then individual lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30177812/partition-data-coming-from-csv-so-i-can-process-larger-patches-rather-then-indiv/30178170#30178170)

Comment: Thanks, that's easiest, didn't know that a bundle had the execution semantic of not being called in parallel on the process method.