# How to Batch elements together with keys

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to convert the first value into the second:

```
PCollection<KV<Integer, List<T>>>
PCollection<KV<String, List<List<T>>>>
```

Input values were already grouped by key.
Output values should be batches of T-s, whose total length would be up to certain size.
Output key would be some new key, for example `"<firstInputKeyInBatch>-<totalBatchSize>"`.

The main goal is to save variable-length sequences to files of roughly the same size, while not splitting a sequence between different files.

Note that built-in `GroupIntoBatches` operates on ungrouped PCollections, and kind of *splits* the values under key, while I need to batch them. Its documentation says `Batches will contain only elements of a single key`, but how to make batches to be composed of multiple keys?

I tried other answers [1], [2], but the problem I'm facing is that `@FinishBundle` method is called per each original Integer key, so my batches end up being effectively the same as input. E.g. all output keys end with `"-1"`.

```java
private List<List<T>> batch = new ArrayList<>();
private Integer lastKey = null;
private Integer numKeys = 0;

public void processElement(KV<Integer, List<T>> input, ...) {
    batch.add(input.getValue());
    lastKey = input.getKey();
    numKeys++;
    if (batch.size() > 10) {
       // ... flush the batch ...
    }
}

String generateBatchId() {
    return lastKey + "-" + numKeys;
}

@FinishBundle
public void finishBundle(FinishBundleContext context) {
    Instant timestamp = GlobalWindow.INSTANCE.maxTimestamp();
    context.output(KV.of(generateBatchId(), batch), timestamp, GlobalWindow.INSTANCE);
    batch = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

[1] [Can datastore input in google dataflow pipeline be processed in a batch of N entries at a time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35065109/can-datastore-input-in-google-dataflow-pipeline-be-processed-in-a-batch-of-n-ent/35068341)

[2] [Partition data coming from CSV so I can process larger patches rather then individual lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30177812/partition-data-coming-from-csv-so-i-can-process-larger-patches-rather-then-indiv/30178170#30178170)

I also tried using stateful processing, like in the `GroupIntoBatches` implementation, but the state variables are also local to an input key. Also, its implementation doesn't handle batch processing (the batch never gets outputed).

Comment: How many input items are you working with? If it's a very small amount, it might be that there's only enough for one item per batch - this is also runner dependent. I got something working with code along the lines of what you have here which started doing any batching (ie. ends with -2 or more) if the input collection was more than ~30 with directrunner.

Comment: @RyanM The input values can range from 1 to 1 million (somewhat exponentially distributed with long tail of small sequences). The number of keys in input PCollection is around 100k. I would want the output PCollection to have around 1000 distinct keys. I feel like the problem is that to obtain the input PCollection I used GroupByKey, which kinda defined that "bundles" correspond to keys.

Comment: To have a better view on what is happening I recommend to create logs using the org.slf4j.LoggerFactory: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/logging#worker_log_message_code_example, I would log the batch IDs to make sure they are generated well.